# How to show/push a navigation controller programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Using a storyboard, I can have a controller have a show/push segue to a navigation controller. The new navigation controller then will have the navigationController set to the existing navigation controller and the view controllers of the new navigation controller will have the new navigation controller as their navigation controllers. If I try programmatically pushing a navigation controller it fails though. Is there any programatic way of modifying the view controllers of a navigation controller so that they can contain a navigation controller? The following won't work:

```
let aNavigationController = UIStoryboard(name: "OurStoryBoard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OurNavigationController") as OurNavigationController

navigationController!.pushViewControll(aNavigationController, animated: true)
```

Comment: I think you might mean "programmatic" instead of "pragmatic". Can you show your code of what you have tried and describe a specific issue that you cannot resolve? This question is currently too vague.

Comment: swap let with var. Do you get any errors ?

Comment: NickCatib, that does not have an effect. View controllers and most everything provided by apple libraries are classes and not structs. The let keyword just means it cannot be re-assigned. It can still be mutated.

Comment: I'm starting to think it might just be bad form to push a navigation controller even though apple allows you to do it through storyboards for some reason. I'm assuming there is some sort of private API they use that we unfortunately don't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

NavigationControllers do not push each other. You can replace a NavigationController with another one, but that will not involve a "pushing" animation.

You can, however, set different view controllers on the same Navigation Controller and have an animation. These will replace the existing view controllers inside the Navigation Controller. Here's an example to push one View Controller and replace any existing view controllers inside the navigation controller:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ViewControllerOne *vc1 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerOne"];
NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray array];
[controllers addObject:vc1];
[yourAppNavigationController setViewControllers:controllers animated:YES];
```

If you want to replace the current view controller(s) with multiple view controllers:

```
// 1.
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
FirstViewController *vc1 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];
SecondViewController *vc2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
ThirdViewController *vc3 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThirdViewController"];

// 2.
NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray array];
[controllers addObject:vc1];
[controllers addObject:vc2];
[controllers addObject:vc3];

// 3.
[yourAppNavigationController setViewControllers:controllers animated:YES];
```

Again, this involves the "pushing" animation that you are probably looking for, and it replaces the existing view controllers so there won't be an undesired back button (in the first code example w/ one VC).